# React MUI DataGrid: enabling checkboxSelection causes Warning: React does not recognize the `touchRippleRef` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui, datagrid

> Warning: React does not recognize the `touchRippleRef` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `touchrippleref` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

I am running into this warning when I have the `checkboxSelection` on my MUI DataGrid. I do not get this error when I remove the prop. Here my component:

```
const columns = [
  { field: 'adset_budget', headerName: 'Adset Budget' },
  { field: 'spend', headerName: 'Spend', type: 'number' },
  { field: 'impressions', headerName: 'Impressions', type: 'number' },
  { field: 'revenue', headerName: 'Revenue', type: 'number' },
];

function DataTable({
  loading,
  metricsData,
}) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', height: 1000 }}>
      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        columns={columns}
        rows={metricsData}
        loading={loading}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

`metricsData` looks like so:

```
[
  {
    {
      "adset_budget": 8434.25,
      "spend": 1437.797094,
      "impressions": 283275,
      "clicks": 33652,
      "revenue": 1953.063728314,
      "id": "2172a7e8-130a"
    },
    {
      "adset_budget": 9434.89,
      "spend": 438.700094,
      "impressions": 573957,
      "clicks": 46365,
      "revenue": 2745.063728746,
      "id": "8972n0e8-987b"
    },
    {
      etc...
    }
  }  
]
```

Appreciate any ideas on how I can fix this warning.

Comment: Why do you have `checkboxSelection` and `disableSelectionOnClick` at the same time?

Comment: So that the row will only be selected when you click the checkbox. Without `disableSelectionOnClick` the row will get selected when you click anywhere on the row.